# При каждом запросе появляется новая сессия

Tags: javascript, node.js, сессия, express

Проблема заключается в том, что при каждом отправке запроса, я получаю новую сессию. Проблема кроется в `credentials`. Ставил и `same-origin` все равно ничего не дает. Я отправляю запрос на /signin и на /account. Мне нужно что все запросы осуществлялись на одной сессии.

Вот сервер:

```js
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 8080);

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors({ origin: '*' }));
app.use(
  session({
    store: new MongoStore({
      url: `mongodb://UserES6:foobar@localhost:27017/${config.db.name}`,
    }),
    secret: 'thisismysupersecret',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    cookie: {
      httpOnly: false, // key
      maxAge: null,
    },
  })
);

const server = app.listen(config.serverPort, () => {
  console.log(`server is up on ${config.serverPort} port`);
});
app.use('/', authRouter);
```

Запросы:

```js
  SignIn(data) {
    return fetch(`${apiPrefix}/signin`, {
      method: 'POST',
      credentials: 'same-origin',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(data),
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => console.log('Response', data))
      .catch(console.error);
  }

  getUser() {
    return fetch(`${apiPrefix}/account`, {
      method: 'POST',
      credentials: 'same-origin',
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .catch(console.error);
  },
```

Роутеры:

```js
router.post('/signin', (req, res, next) => {
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
  user.findOne(
    { username: req.body.username, password: req.body.password },
    function (err, user) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return res.status(500).send();
      }

      if (!user) {
        return res.status(404).send();
      }

      req.session.user = user;
      return res.status(200).send();
    }
  );
});

router.post('/account', function (req, res) {
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
  console.log(req.session.user);
  if (!req.session.user) return res.status(401).send();
  return res.send(req.session.user);
});
```

Если использовать `credentials: 'include'` то с header, он не работает, а на сервер приходит undefined, но с одной сессией работает.
Как реализовать работу запросов, чтоб на /signin он отправлял данные на одну сессию, а при вызове /account запрос работал с этой же сессией?

Answer (score 0):

в конфиг куки

```
 cookie: {
        httpOnly: false, // key
        maxAge: null
    }
```

попробуйте добавить

```
 path: "/"
```